# How do I run win32-openssh through the powershell? (installed with install-package from chocolatey provider)

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

So I am just trying to convert to powershell from bash. I was trying to find a way to SSH my server, and found out I could install win32-openssh to do so.

I installed it by:

1. Installing chocolatey as packageprovider using:

   install-packageprovider chocolatey
2. Then i installed win32-openssh with the command:

   install-package win32-openssh

My problem is now, how do I run this program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It installs the correct binaries etc. It will not add some PS cmdlets for the use off ssh inside PS.

It is all described on the [package site](https://chocolatey.org/packages/win32-openssh):

> This package performs the following operations that you normally have to hack at until you get what you want:
>
> - Install Appropriate Bitness for the version of Windows
> - Install to Program Files (malware protection and following advice of dev team)
> - Add SSH location to System PATH
> - Optionally install sshd windows service (Requires parameter - see below)
> - Optionally install sshd server "key based authentication" (Requires parameter - see below)
> - Cleanly uninstall all of the above (removing config files and server keys requires special switch - see below)

So you can run it from start menu, or by typing `ssh.exe` into a prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You have Two Options I can think of.

- Option 1 : Use bash on Windows 10. Bash comes bundled with Windows 10. You can just enable a Windows 10 feature for it. [Setup bash on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-bash-shell-command-line-windows-10). You'll never miss bash again even if you're on Windows. [**Recommended Option**]
- Option 2 : Set up SSH on Powershell by installing a package like **PoSH-SSH**.

Steps :

Pre-requisite : PC running **Windows 10**. Open *PowerShell* in **Admin mode**.

1. `Find-Module PoSH-SSH`

   type 'Y' for the prompts.
2. `Install-Module Posh-SSH`

   type 'A' for the prompts.

Reference:
https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2016/04/using-ssh-with-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a need for this. If you have git installed on your Windows machine, you can add it's usr/bin folder to you path. It has ssh and other Unix tools you can use just like in Bash in PowerShell or CMD.